# Server 2008 R2 Core installation, drivers?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, windows-server-core

I have the server core OS installed with network and raid controller drivers installed. What other drivers are necessary?  With GUI, you typically install chipset, vga, audio (if supported), sata controller, etc...

Comment: You might as well install all of them.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no reason not to install all available drivers, especially chipset. Not having a point-and-click GUI doesn't mean you should leave your system in a partially-installed state.

Comment: What if there's no cmd-line method of installation? Seems like everything runs a GUI for installs.

Comment: Most drivers I have seen that are intended for **use on server hardware** have a way to get or extract the bare driver an inf files so you can include them within an automated deployment setup.  You just have to search to find them.

Comment: I can't think of a single driver that I've ever seen that's point-and-click only. Usually a copy of 7zip can extract the contents and then you can cram the .inf into your WDS/MDT/offline .wim

Comment: @MDMarra - Broadcom driver with teaming :-)